# Show that for every three linear maps $A, B, C: V → V$ we have $rk(ABC) ≤ rk(B)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $V$ be a vector space. Show that for every three linear maps $$A, B, C: V → V$$ we have  $$rk(ABC) ≤ rk(B)$$

My only idea is to try and show something like  $rk(ABC) ≤ rk(BC) ≤ rk(B)$, but very unsure how to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The image of $fg$ is contained in the image of $f$ and the kernel of $g$ is contained in the kernel of $fg$.  First convert "contained" into an inequality of dimensions and then use the rank nullity theorem to convert dimensions of kernels to dimensions of images.

Comment: Okay so I can see that we can say something about rk(BC)≤rk(B) by saying BC is contained in B. But i dont follow the kernel part .

Comment: What inequality do you get for the kernels?

Comment: i dont even know why it is that kernel of g is contained in the kernel of fg, that doesnt seem correct.

Comment: @123454321 Well, if $v\in\mathrm{Ker}g$, then $g(v)=0$, so $(f\circ g)(v)=f(g(v))=f(0)=0$, thus $v\in\mathrm{Ker}fg$.